# Print blocked signals in Pending Signal Queue in C

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, signals

The signals when blocked are added to the pending queue and are delivered only when they are unblocked. I would like to block a certain signals, and unblock them only when all of them are in the pending queue. Is there a mechanism or a system call that I can use to print the pending signals for my process.

Comment: There is no special requirement. Just trying an application, where I want to unblock a set of signals only, when the signals are received in a certain order. Off course this can be done using signal handlers, but I would like the signals to remain blocked until they are received in a certain order.

Answer (score 2):

Check `man sigpending` manual page:

> sigpending() returns the set of signals that are pending for delivery
>          to the calling thread (i.e., the signals which have been raised while
>          blocked).  The mask of pending signals is returned in set.